# Installing a .pfx Cert in TrustedRootCA WITH private key from command line in powershell on win7

Tags: powershell, ssl

My question is this: how would I go about installing a .pfx cert into TrustedRootCA with its private key from command line using powershell in windows 7?

I've got it to install the cert using this command: certutil -importpfx -p "mypasswordhere" "cert path location here"

The above installs it to the personal store of the local computer fine (With the private key intact) And also installs it to TRCA, only without the private key. This is my issue as the program requires the TRCA to have the private key.

but when I try to use the program that needs the cert it says : "It is likely that "My cert" may not have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have axxess rights for the private key. Please see inner exception for more detail.

However, I checked the TRCA store and verfied that my cert indeed does not have its private key.

So again my question is there anyway using powershell to automate this process on windows 7? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This applies to Windows 10 as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\setup\TestCertImport.pfx -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\LocalMachine\Root'
```

Root = Trusted root, 
My = Local Machine Personal certificate folder

if the certificate has password you can add the -Password parameter and if you want it to be exportable the -Exportable

Comment: I wish I could but I have to use CertUtil as its on windows 7 PS